# Apply vba function to cell directly above button

Tags: excel, vba, button, copy

In my vba code the goal is to add 500 to the cell above the button. Right now the button in question is in cell "c7". I want the cell directly above it which is cell be "b7" to add 500 every time the button is pressed. I would like to copy the button to add for cells throughout the worksheet. So the code has to be something like cell.above +500 or something like that. I added my current code below.

[image]

```
Range("b7").Value = Range("b7").Value + 500
```

Comment: So you told us what you want to do. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Look at `Application.Caller` and `TopLeftCell` if you need to get the location of a button calling your code.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I dont know how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a form button, it's like this:

```
Sub FormButtonClick()
With Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    .Value = IIF(Not IsNumeric(.Value),500,.Value + 500)
End With
End Sub
```

You can add the `IIF` to see if it's blank and "initialize" it at `500` (or whatever) if that's you're desire.

[image: Demo]

Make sure you're looking at the right sheet - this was added in the `Sheet1` object code module.

Otherwise, you may need to specify a sheet.

Also, when you're copying them, you need to rename them (by default they are copied with the same name).

Comment: Side note, but `IsNumeric` actually returns `True` for an empty cell.

Comment: Yeah - I was trying to code around it, but doesn't even look like an issue since an empty cell is considered `0` anyway. Would help if you had text there I guess, but probably doesn't matter either way. I'd just change to `.Value = .Value + 500` like I had originally.