# excel button connected to macro having runtime issue

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement, iif

My vba code connected to a button is crashing on runtime. It is stating sub or function not defined. I am new to vba code so I dont know how to solve this. It appears that the method is closed so I dont know why this is not working. I have added a photo below.

[image: photo]

```
Sub FormButtonClick()
With Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    .Value = IIf(Not IsNumeric(.Value), 500, .Value + 500)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Shapes` is not a member of the default `Application` object, so try `With Sheet1.Shapes(...)`  or `ActiveSheet.Shapes`   If your code were in a worksheet module it would work (assuming the button is on the same sheet), because there the default "root" object is that worksheet.

Comment: ....I would assume it was tested in a sheet module when posted in answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72219644/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams what you said worked